# Matplotlib: annotating plots with arbitrary shapes

Tags: annotations, matplotlib

Hi I would like to be able to add arbitrary shapes to an x-y plot.  Here's an example:

[image]

As you can see in the above plot, there's a horizontal annotation line that contains arrows and cylinders.  Ultimately I'd like to be able to pass a list of chars [None, "a","a","a",None,"c","c","c", None, etc...] and add that annotation below the plot, or on the x-axis.

Can someone please suggest a way to do this, or comment if it's even possible.  Also if adding arrows/cylinders is too difficult, just adding different color of simple rectangles will be fine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible to add shapes like you describe to at maplotlib axes object. See this example:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/shapes_and_collections/artist_reference.html

So you need to do two things:

1. use `ax.get_xlim()` and `np.linspace(xmin, xmax, num_shapes)` to figure out the x-coordinates of your each of your artists
2. write a function to add the shapes as shown in the example with the axes object, artist type, and x-y coordinates as arguments.